# Postgres reverse inheritance? (inherit rows from parent table)

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, union, reverse

I have a number of records that are common to all schemas. I place these records in a shared schema table, and would like to inheritthe  rows of record from this shared parent table in each of the child schemas.

Suppose I have the following schemas:

```
CREATE SCHEMA parent; 
CREATE SCHEMA a;
CREATE SCHEMA b;

CREATE TABLE parent.component (product_id serial PRIMARY KEY, title text);
CREATE TABLE a.component () INHERITS (parent.component); 
CREATE TABLE b.product () INHERITS (parent.component); 

INSERT INTO parent.component(title) VALUES ('parent'); 
INSERT INTO a.component(title) VALUES ('a_test') ,('a_test2') ;
INSERT INTO b.component(title) VALUES ('b_test') ,('b_test2');
```

Is there a way to select the union of rows from the `parent` and either `a.component` or `b.component` when I issue a select on either `a` or `b` ?

So for example:

```
SELECT * FROM a.component;
```

returns rows:

```
id   |   title
---------------
1        parent
2        a_test
3        a_test2
```

Comment: This is very interesting idea but inheritance unfortunately (or maybe fortunately - to avoid problems with logic) does not allow it. Table "a.component" is child therefore it cannot see rows neither from parent table nor from other children. But I believe you know you can simply use "UNION ALL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has multiple inheritance, so a table can be the child of many tables. You could try to inherit in the other direction!

But maybe a simple `UNION ALL` query is a simpler and better solution.

Comment: I think I'd just go with the union because it might get messy to get a global sequence for ensuring safe updates/deletes. Thanks.